# Generating jQuery mobile "pages" dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, mobile

I'm doing a college assignment with jQuery Mobile and JSON. Best practice with jQuery mobile is my main concern.

My html starts off with a main 'page' (data-role="page") inside a div with id="all-pages".

I use jQuery's `.getJSON` method to connect to a local JSON file called profiles.json. profiles.json contains an array called profiles and has multiple objects. I loop through this in my jQuery and generate a list item (which is inserted to the main 'page') for each profile. I also generate a 'page' (ie data-role="page") for each profile and link to it in the list item.

Before I make the `getJSON` request, I created variables that store html such as the 'header', that will be used on every page in order to try not to repeat my code. I still have a lot of jQuery code to generate the html. I am wondering if I can make it more efficient? I.e. Is there a best practice when it comes to generating pages dynamically in jQuery Mobile?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="all-pages">
    <div data-role="page" id="page-home" data-theme="a">
        <!--this is the main 'page' in the app and it is static html. All other 'pages' will be generated dynamically-->
        <!--The number of pages that exist will depend on how many profiles exist in the profiles.json file-->
        <!--The number of profiles will also indicate how many list items will exist on the main page.-->

        <div data-role="header">
            <!--The home icon will be placed on the left side of the header on every page.-->
            <a id="home-button" href="#page-home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Home button</a>
            <h1>The Random Network</h1>

            <!--use the ui-btn-right class to position the bars icon to the right of the header.-->
            <a id="panel-button" href="#right-panel" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" >Panel button</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-primary">
                <div data-demo-html="true">
                    <div>
                        <p>Welcome to the Random Network, where all kinds of random objects and things can socialize and meet new objects.</p>          
                    </div>
                    <!--use the data-filter-placeholder to customize the text in the filter input field. data-filter-reveal=true in order to only reveal the items after they match the input-->
                    <ul id="list-of-profiles" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search objects..." data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-filter-reveal="false">
                        <!--these list items will be created dynamically from the profiles.json file-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Copyright Inanimate Objects</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--All other 'pages' will be generated dynamically and will be placed here-->
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var header = '<div data-role="header">' +
            '<a id="home-button" href="#page-home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Home button</a>' +
            '<a id="panel-button" href="#right-panel" class="ui-btn-right noshadow" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Panel  button</a>' +
            '<h2>The Random Network</h2></div>';
        var content = '<div data-role="content">' +
                '<div class="content-primary"><!--this class content-primary is necessary for the panel--></div></div>';


        var intro_section = '<div class="intro">' +
                    '<img class="profile-photo large-image" width="250" heigh="250" />' +
                    '<h3 class="profile-name"></h3>' +
                    '<p class="intro-paragraph"></p></div><!--End Intro-->';
        var post_list = '<ul class="list-of-posts" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search posts..." data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-filter-reveal="false"></ul>';

        //this is necessary so that we can access our panel on all pages.
        $("body>[data-role='panel']").panel();  

        $.getJSON('profiles.json',{
                format: "json"
        }).done(function(data){
        var count = 0;
            $.each(data.profiles, function(i, profile){
            var id = profile.id;
            var first_name = profile.first_name;
            var last_name = profile.last_name;
            var intro = profile.intro_paragraph;
            var img_src = profile.profile_picture;
            console.log(first_name);
            var page_id = "page-" + profile.id;
            var list_id = "list-" + count;
            var anchor_id = "anchor-" + count;

            //generate a list item for each profile
            $("<li>").attr("id", list_id).attr("class", "list-item").appendTo("#list-of-profiles");
            $("<a>").attr("id", anchor_id).attr("data-transition", "pop").attr("href", "#" + page_id).appendTo("#" + list_id);
            $("<img>").attr("src", img_src).attr("class", "profile-thumbnail").attr("width", "50").attr("height", "50").appendTo("#" + anchor_id);
            $("<h3>" + first_name + "</h3>").appendTo("#" + anchor_id);
            $("<p>" + intro + "</p>").appendTo("#" + anchor_id);

            //generate pages for each profile
            $("<div>" + header + "</div>").attr("data-role", "page").attr("id", page_id).attr("data-theme", "a").appendTo("#all-pages");

            //$("#all-pages").append('<div data-role="page" id="' + page_id + '" data-theme="a">' + header + '</div>');
            $("#" + page_id).append(content);
            $("#" + page_id + " .content-primary").append(intro_section);
            $("#" + page_id + " .profile-photo").attr("src", img_src);
            $("#" + page_id + " .profile-name").html(first_name);
            $("#" + page_id + " .intro-paragraph").html(intro);
            $("#" + page_id + " .content-primary").append(post_list);

            console.log("intro" + intro);
            $.each(profile.posts, function(i, post){
                //go through the posts array and store information about each post into local variables.
                var post_id = "post-id-" + post.id;         //each post in the json file will have a unique 'id'
                var time = post.time;
                var date = post.date;
                var update_comment = post.update_comment;   
                var quantity_trophies = post.gifts.trophies;    //number of trophies is stored in the gifts array within the post object.
                var quantity_love = post.gifts.love;        //number of loves is stored in the gifts array within the post object.
                var quantity_thumbs_up = post.gifts.thumbs_up;  //number of thumbs_up is stored in the gifts array within the post object.
                var update_type = post.update_type; //this will be either 'status', 'photo' or 'video'

                console.log(update_type);

                //generate a list item for each post and give it an id of the post_id created above.
                $("<li>").attr("id", post_id).attr("class", "post").appendTo("#" + page_id + " .list-of-posts");
                $("<h4>" + first_name + "'s update</h4>").appendTo("#" + post_id);
                $("<p>" + time + " " + date + "</p>").attr("class", "post-date").appendTo("#" + post_id);
                $("<div>").attr("class", "update-area").appendTo("#" + post_id);
                $("<div>").attr("class", "update-comment").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-area");
                $("<span>").attr("class", "profile-thumbnail").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-comment");
                $("<img>").attr("src", img_src).attr("width", "50").attr("height", "50").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .profile-thumbnail");
                $("<p>").attr("class", "comment-name").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-comment");
                $("<a>" + first_name + "</a>").attr("data-transition", "pop").attr("href", "#" + page_id).appendTo("#" + post_id + " .comment-name");
                $("<p>" + update_comment +"</p>").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-comment");

                if(update_type == "photo"){
                    //if the update type is a photo then get the link of the photo from the json file
                    var update_photo = post.update_photo;

                    //add a div tag with a class of photo-area (for styling) and append it to the update-area
                    $("<div>").attr("class", "photo-area").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-area");

                    //create an image tag and use the update_photo link as the src of the image.
                    //append this img tag to the photo-area we created above.
                    $("<img>").attr("class", "large-image").attr("src", update_photo).appendTo("#" + post_id + " .photo-area");
                }

                if(update_type == "video"){
                    //get the video link from the current 'post' array.
                    var video_link = post.video_link; 

                    //firstly check if the video link contains the string "youtu.be/"
                    //That way we know if it's a youtube video and will therefore use an iframe tag
                    //and format the youtube string in the right way in order to embed the video
                    if(video_link.indexOf("youtu.be/") != -1){
                        //if the upate type is a video and it is a youtube link then we will need to add a div with a class of 
                        //'video-wrapper' in order to create a fluid width video.
                        //we will apend video-wrapper to the update-area div
                        $("<div>").attr("class", "video-wrapper").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-area");

                            //get the code at the end of the youtube string so that we can embed the video to an iframe.
                        var youtube_code = video_link.substr(video_link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                        //Now we create a string which follows youtube's link format for embedding videos
                        //concatenate the youtube code we generated from the video link above, onto the embed string.
                        var youtube_embed_link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + youtube_code;

                        //Create an iframe tag with the source equal to the embed string we created. 
                        //append the iframe to the div with class=video-wrapper
                        $("<iframe>").attr("src", youtube_embed_link).attr("width", "560").attr("height", "315").attr("frameborder", "0").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .video-wrapper");
                    }else if(video_link.indexOf(".mp4") != -1){

                        //if the video link is not a youtube link and contains .mp4 than use a 
                        //html5 video tag and use the video_link as the source.
                        //we will set the width of the video to 100% and the height to auto. 
                        $("<video>").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "auto").attr("controls", true).appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-area");
                        $("<source>").attr("src", video_link).attr("type", "video/mp4").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-area video");
                        $("<source>").attr("src", video_link).attr("type", "video/webm").appendTo("#" + post_id + " .update-area video");
                        //if the users browser does not support html5 video then we will display a message.
                        //We need to append the message to the video tag as a fallback
                        $(".update-area video").append("Your browser does not support HTML5 video");    
                    }
                }   


                //add in the gift area, where we show what "gifts" the user has received from other users for a particular 'post'
                $("<div>").attr("class", "gift-area").appendTo("#" + post_id);

                if(quantity_trophies != 0){
                    //if there are zero trophies in the json file for this post then do not display the trophy symbol
                    var trophy_title = "" + quantity_trophies + " trophies received"; //create a string for the title attribute
                    $('<span><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>(' + quantity_trophies + ')</span>').attr("class", "gift").attr("title", trophy_title).appendTo("#" + post_id + " .gift-area");

                }
                if(quantity_love != 0){
                    //if there are zero loves in the json file for this post then do not display the heart symbol
                    var love_title = "" + quantity_love + " loves received"; //create a string for the title attribute
                    $('<span><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>(' + quantity_love + ')</span>').attr("class", "gift").attr("title", love_title).appendTo("#" + post_id + " .gift-area");
                    }
                if(quantity_thumbs_up != 0){
                    //if there are zero thumbs up in the json file for this post then do not display the thumbs up symbol
                    var thumbs_up_title = "" + quantity_thumbs_up + " thumbs up received"; //create a string for the title attribute
                    $('<span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>(' + quantity_thumbs_up + ')</span>').attr("class", "gift").attr("title", thumbs_up_title).appendTo("#" + post_id + " .gift-area");
                    }

                var comment_count = 0;  //set up a counter so we can create a unique class name for each user comment
                $.each(post.user_comments, function(i, comment){
                    //we go through this loop for each user comment
                    var comment_first_name = comment.first_name;        //this will be the name of the the user who commented
                    var comment_page_id = "page-" + comment.id;     //this will be the id of the profile page of the user who commented
                    var comment_picture = comment.profile_picture;  //this will be the profile picture of the the user who commented

                    //want to create unique class names for the different "comment-area"s and "comment-main"s so we can target them.
                    //every "comment-area" will have one "comment-main" div and possible "comment-reply" divs
                    //we will loop through the "comment-reply"s further down.

                    var unique_comment_area = "comment-area-" + comment_count; //create unique class name
                    var unique_comment_main = "comment-main-" + comment_count; //create unique class name

                    //create a div with a unique_comment_area class (in order to select this specific div) and also "comment-area" class (in order to apply css styling)
                    //and append this div to the current Post in the loop.
                    $("<div>").attr("class", unique_comment_area).addClass("comment-area").appendTo("#" + post_id);

                    $("<div>").attr("class", unique_comment_main).addClass("comment-main").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area);
                    $("<span>").attr("class", "profile-thumbnail").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_comment_main);
                    $("<img>").attr("src", comment_picture).attr("width", "50").attr("height", "50").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_comment_main + " .profile-thumbnail");
                    $("<p>").attr("class", "comment-name").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_main);
                    $("<a>" + comment_first_name + "</a>").attr("data-transition", "pop").attr("href", "#" + comment_page_id).appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_main + " .comment-name");
                    $("<p>" + comment.user_comment + "</p>").attr("class", "photo-comment").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_main);


                    var reply_count = 0; //set up a counter so we can create a unique class name for each reply
                    $.each(comment.replies, function(i, reply){
                        var reply_first_name = reply.first_name;    //this will be the name of the the user who replied to the first comment
                        var reply_page_id = "page-" + reply.id;     //this will be the id of the profile page of the user who replied
                        var reply_picture = reply.profile_picture;  //this will be the profile picture of the the user who replied      
                        var unique_reply_class = "comment-reply-" + reply_count; //create unique class name

                        $("<div>").attr("class", unique_reply_class).addClass("comment-reply").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area);
                        $("<span>").attr("class", "profile-thumbnail").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_reply_class);
                        $("<img>").attr("src", reply_picture).attr("width", "50").attr("height", "50").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_reply_class + " .profile-thumbnail");
                        $("<p>").attr("class", "comment-name").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_reply_class);
                        $("<a>" + reply_first_name + "</a>").attr("data-transition", "pop").attr("href", "#" + reply_page_id).appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_reply_class + " .comment-name");
                        $("<p>" + reply.user_comment + "</p>").attr("class", "photo-comment").appendTo("#" + post_id + " ." + unique_comment_area + " ." + unique_reply_class);

                        reply_count++;
                    }); 
                    comment_count++;    
                });
            });
        count++;        
            });

        $('#list-of-profiles').listview('refresh'); 
        });

    });
```

**JSON:**

```
{"profiles":[   {"id":"0001",
        "first_name":"Vicki",
        "last_name":"Phillips",
        "profile_picture":"images/img-0001-1.jpg",
        "intro_paragraph":"hi ya'll. I'm the token human on this site.",
        "posts":[{"id":"0001-0001",
            "date":"22-04-2016",
            "time":"19:01",
            "update_type":"status",
            "update_comment":"Had an amazing time at the beach today.",
            "user_comments":[{"id":"0003",
                    "first_name":"Mr Bush",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "profile_picture":"images/img-0003-1.jpg", 
                    "user_comment":"lucky you",
                    "replies":[{"id":"0001",
                        "first_name":"Vicki",
                        "last_name":"Phillips",
                        "profile_picture":"images/img-0001-1.jpg", 
                        "user_comment":"Thanks"},
                        {"id":"0002",
                        "first_name":"Pie",
                        "last_name":"",
                        "profile_picture":"images/img-0002-1.jpg", 
                        "user_comment":"Your Welcome"}]
                    },
                    {"id":"0002",
                    "first_name":"Pie",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "profile_picture":"images/img-0002-1.jpg", 
                    "user_comment":"oh",
                    "replies":[{"id":"0001",
                        "first_name":"Vicki",
                        "last_name":"Phillips",
                        "profile_picture":"images/img-0001-1.jpg", 
                        "user_comment":"Thanks"},
                        {"id":"0002",
                        "first_name":"Pie",
                        "last_name":"",
                        "profile_picture":"images/img-0002-1.jpg", 
                        "user_comment":"Your Welcome"}]
                    }],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"0","love":"4","thumbs_up":"3"}},
            {"id":"0001-0002",
            "date":"14-04-2016",
            "time":"17:01",
            "update_type":"status",
            "update_comment":"Totes excited today.",
            "user_comments":[],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"13","love":"4","thumbs_up":"3"}},
            {"id":"0001-0003",
            "date":"02-04-2016",
            "time":"18:01",
            "update_type":"photo",
            "update_comment":"Got a new job working for VirtualRealty. Yippeeee!",
            "update_photo":"images/img-0002-2.jpg",
            "user_comments":[{"id":"0002",
                    "first_name":"Pie",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "profile_picture":"images/img-0002-1.jpg", 
                    "user_comment":"Well done!! Trophy for you",
                    "replies":[{"id":"0001",
                        "first_name":"Vicki",
                        "last_name":"Phillips",
                        "profile_picture":"images/img-0001-1.jpg", 
                        "user_comment":"Thanks. I'm very happy"},
                        {"id":"0002",
                        "first_name":"Pie",
                        "last_name":"",
                        "profile_picture":"images/img-0002-1.jpg", 
                        "user_comment":"Your Welcome"}]
                    }],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"20","love":"11","thumbs_up":"6"}},
            {"id":"0001-0004",
            "date":"05-03-2016",
            "time":"15:01",
            "update_type":"video",
            "update_comment":"One of my all time favorite songs!",
            "video_link":"https://youtu.be/9ro0FW9Qt-4",
            "user_comments":[{"id":"0003",
                    "first_name":"Mr Bush",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "profile_picture":"images/img-0003-1.jpg", 
                    "user_comment":"Wow! Brings me back",
                    "replies":[]
                    }],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"0","love":"12","thumbs_up":"3"}},
            {"id":"0001-0005",
            "date":"05-03-2016",
            "time":"15:01",
            "update_type":"video",
            "update_comment":"Came across this lil video today. love it!",
            "video_link":"videos/mov_bbb.mp4",
            "user_comments":[{"id":"0003",
                    "first_name":"Mr Bush",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "profile_picture":"images/img-0003-1.jpg", 
                    "user_comment":"Aw cute!!",
                    "replies":[]
                    }],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"0","love":"5","thumbs_up":"1"}}]
        },
        {"id":"0002",
        "first_name":"Pie",
        "last_name":"",
        "profile_picture":"images/img-0002-1.jpg",
        "intro_paragraph":"pieeee.",
        "posts":[{"id":"0002-0001",
            "date":"24-01-2014",
            "time":"19:01",
            "update_type":"status",
            "update_comment":"pieeeee.",
            "user_comments":[],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"13","love":"4","thumbs_up":"3"}},
            {"id":"0002-0002",
            "date":"24-01-2014",
            "time":"19:01",
            "update_type":"status",
            "update_comment":"pieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.",
            "user_comments":[],
            "gifts":{"trophies":"13","love":"4","thumbs_up":"3"}}]
        }]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a JS template engine like http://handlebarsjs.com/ if this is appropriate for your project. In your HTML file you can define several templates wrapped in a  tag:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

in you JS you define all the *{{vars}}*, optional compile the template (performance, especially for mobile), then let jQ append it:

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
var html    = template(context);
$('#myDiv').append(html);
```

But once you do, the template vars are fix you cannot change them. You cannot nest these templates. handlebarsjs is not the only, but the most common template engine

Comment: This looks good however for this project we are not required to use a template engine. I was mainly wondering If I have used any bad practices in my jQuery code when generating the html code dynamically? thanks for your help :)